# dump XML into MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I've got a database dump in XML coming from some Windows application. I believe its SQL Server 2008 data dumped into XML via C#, although I do not have access to the source. I only have the dump.

The XML file matches this format:
[MSDN DataTable::WriteXmlSchema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb6w5k4e.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1)

Is there a known / convenient way to import this into MySQL? Is there anything in VisualStudio or MySQL Workbench that might help?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL (as of version 5.5) has a LOAD XML syntax, see this link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html

If your data doesn't fit that schema, you might be able to transform it into that schema.

Otherwise, you could use the ODBC .NET Managed Provider to talk to MySQL from C# (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310988), although I don't know whether it has been tested, or whether it is supported for MySQL.

From there you could parse the XML and create insert statements, etc.

Or, if you can't get the ODBC provider working, you could write a program to parse the XML, and write the appropriate SQL statements to insert all the data.

In short, you get to have fun with this.

Comment: Didn't think of it at first, but I'm going to see if I can import the MS XML file back into SQL Server, then just export it as SQL.

Comment: I tried LOAD XML first but it was giving me syntax errors although I followed the instructions exactly, just changing the file name appropriately. The thought I just posted above will probably be easier in the long run because I have like 10 tables I need to do this with.

Comment: Are you trying to load Schema, or Data? I don't believe SQL Server will script out data for you. But if you are trying to ouput the schema, then scripting it out is your best bet.